# Sphinx cannot find module but Python can

Tags: python, module, package, python-sphinx

Sphinx, the Python documentation generator, does not seem to understand my modules/packages. On `make clean && make html`, when this code is ran: `from statstuff import statistics as stats`, it outputs:

> ImportError: No module named 'statstuff'

I have also tried to reference the module as `from . import statistics as stats`, since the modules are in the same package, but Sphinx outputs:

> SystemError: Parent module '' not loaded, cannot perform relative import

Also, the `config.py` seems to be correctly configured as `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../statstuff/'))`, given that the documentation folder shares its parent folder with the statstuff folder.

Anyhow, here is the repository with the files: https://github.com/lucasmauro/statstuff

The problem occurs on `statstuff/regression.py`, lines 2 and 3: https://github.com/lucasmauro/statstuff/blob/master/statstuff/regression.py

The code runs normally with the Python interpreters, but Sphinx fails to find the module as the code (or configuration) was written.

Does anyone have a clue on how to solve this?

Thank you very much indeed!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since your modules are in a [package](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) called `statstuff`, I suggest the following:

1. Add the path to the directory *above* `statstuff` to `sys.path` in conf.py:

   ```
   sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..'))
   ```
2. Edit the `automodule` directives. Change

   ```
   .. automodule:: probability
   ```

   to

   ```
   .. automodule:: statstuff.probability
   ```

   and so on.

Comment: mzjn, thank you very much. It worked, but sort of. Everything went inside "statstuff" at the documentation page. Do you have any other ideas?

Comment: *'Everything went inside "statstuff" at the documentation page'*. Is that a problem? You have put your modules in a package called `statstuff` and that should be reflected in the documentation, shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but you could try to set the [add_module_names](http://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/stable/config.html#confval-add_module_names) configuration variable to `False`. This will remove `statstuff.<modname>` from all function names.

Comment: My original idea was that the package statstuff would be the root, such as "src", and the modules or packages inside it (and the tests outside "src"). But I am very new to Python, so my design is not good hehe. This way, setting the sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('..')) works with all modules, so that's fine. I guess I don't really need to treat "statstuff" as the root of the documentation, in the end it does not make great difference. Many thanks, @mzjn. :)