# Sphinx can't find my functions (probably due to imports or folder structure)

Tags: python, python-sphinx, autodoc

I have the following folder structure for a package project (simplified):

```
projectname
├── docs
├── packagename
│   ├── somemodule
│   |   ├── __init__.py (second)
|   │   └── somescript.py
│   └── __init__.py (first)
├── setup.cfg
└── pyproject.toml
```

In first `__init__.py` I do `from . import somemodule`. In the second `__init__.py` I do `from .somescript import *`. And `somescript.py` contains some function `my_sum`. The problem is that sphinx doesn't see the function. It only sees module `packagename.somemodule` - there is no function doscstring for `my_sum` in generated documentation. The function works well if I install the library using `pip install .` from the `projectname` folder.
I'm sure the problem is in the folder structure or imports because there was no problem when `somescript.py` was placed directly in `packagename` folder.

Additional information (maybe useful, maybe not):
I use Read The Docs.
Part of `.readthedocs.yaml`:

```
python:
  install:
    - method: pip
      path: .
```

**UPD**:
Read The Docs generates the following warnings:

```
WARNING: autodoc: failed to import module 'somescript' from module 'packagename'; the following exception was raised:
No module named 'packagename.somescripts'
WARNING: html_static_path entry '_static' does not exist
```

**UPD2**:
I fixed the warning from `autodoc` by fixing `docs/source/packagename.rst` but I still have the problem

Comment: Are there any error messages? Have you added a path to `sys.path`? See (for example) https://stackoverflow.com/q/41925973/407651

Comment: @mzjn no errors, although there are some warnings. I included `sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('.')) ;
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../')) ;
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath('../..'))` in the `conf.py`, if it was your question

Comment: @mzjn it's strange because I have no errors when I install the library locally (from another environment and folder of course)

Comment: @mzjn yes, it was my mistake. Actually, it should be `packagename.somescript`

Comment: @mzjn I'm trying to find the error right now but if I fail I think I will produce the full example. I found that `docs/source/packagename.rst` contains `automodule:: scriptname` but it should (it was only correct before I made folder structure changes). How do I auto-update this file?

Comment: I changed `docs/source/packagename.rst` and it fixed the warning but I still have the problem

Comment: @mzjn there is no instruction to function (from docstrings) in the documentation I generate

Comment: @mzjn basically the generated documentation is empty

Comment: Unless you provide a [mcve], I don't think we can help. Sorry.

Comment: @pascalamin If you're using Read the Docs, can you share the project URL? Most likely this is a configuration problem that should be easy to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I once had a similar problem and it could be solved by manually adding all directories of the module to the path. See also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65125602/8028981).

Comment: The OP has added three paths to `sys.path` already (see the second comment of the question). Usually you need to add one `sys.path` entry: the path to the directory above the top-level package.

Comment: @mzjn Thanks for pointing this out. When I had a siilar issue, it was solved after I manually added all directories containing source files to the path (adding the package's root directory wouldn't suffice). Not sure if I also tried to add the directory above the package's root, though. Anyways, maybe my workaround is worth a try for the OP ...